# Why am I getting a weird, blocky black background on my Windows desktop?

Tags: windows, desktop

[My Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvvM.jpg) looks like this.

[image: My Desktop]

The icons show the desktop background behind them only after hovering over them. It doesn't happen all the time. The desktop became that way upon highlighting it, as you can see.

I am currently using [This XFX GPU](https://www.newegg.com/xfx-radeon-rx-550-rx-550p4lfg5/p/N82E16814150814) as a stand in for my [Nvidia GPU](https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-gtx-1050-ti-gaming-x-4g/p/N82E16814137054?Description=MSI%20GeForce%20GTX%201050%20Ti&cm_re=MSI_GeForce%20GTX%201050%20Ti-_-14-137-054-_-Product&quicklink=true) while it is being repaired. I sent the Nvidia GPU in for repair because of this black background problem.

Originally I had an Intel set up; I bought my Nvidia GPU just before building a new PC entirely. The parts I salvaged from my Intel system build were my PSU and the Nvidia GP I sent in.

I never had this problem before I put the Nvidia GPU in my Intel build, but, now even in my AMD build and with an XFX card I still get this glitch/error.

Note: I also salvaged my HDD and SSD from my old build. That could be the problem. All I have is Windows and it was a fresh install as of 2 or so months ago. This problem is (from what I can tell) cosmetic, I don't get any harmful system errors stops or glitches, but, I rather like my background so I’d like to have it fixed.

As you can see in [my AMD Build](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/FBgmht) I show the parts I salvaged from [this Intel Build](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/cgHJdD). Any part not shown in my Intel build was transferred from it to the AMD build.

That’s all the information I have, though. Thanks to anyone taking the time to help.

Comment: Next time please update your question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: What are you doing at the time the black background appears?  What applications are running that would have access to the AMD display driver?

Comment: The only thing I can guess is Elder Scrolls Online. But IIRC I didn't have that when the problem started.

Comment: Originally I had an Intel set up; I bought my Nvidia GPU just before building a new PC entirely. The parts I salvaged from my Intel system build were my PSU and the Nvidia GP I sent in.    <---- Update BIOS, Chipset if one, and GPU driver. Then if you still have the issue it could be another hardware or Windows 10 compliance issue.

Comment: Is updating bios simple? I've never done it before.

Comment: You follow the manufacturer’s instructions, update the BIOS and there you go. No big deal.